# Spring: Obtaining ResourceBundle based on MessageSource

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring

I'm using hibernate validator framework with Spring. A class implementing the Spring Validator validates objects with Hibernate's ClassValidator. To localize ClassValidator's error messages I need to pass a ResourceBundle into the class' constructor. My ApplicationCountext has a MessageSource bean (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) which is used throught the application. It makes sense to use this same MessafeSource for the ClassValidator. But how do I convert the MessageSource to a ResourceBundle? Is there any adapter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MessageSourceResourceBundle](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceResourceBundle.html) sounds like what you are looking for.  (Haven't tried it myself.)